# dhall Invalid alternative type

Tags: dhall

I've defined a union type with two elements like so:

*FunctionCode.dhall*

```
{- Function Code union -}

let StaticFC = ./StaticFunctionCode.dhall
let DynamicFC = ./DynamicFunctionCode.dhall

in < Static : StaticFC | Dynamic : DynamicFC >
```

The two types, StaticFC and DynamicFC are defined like so:

*StaticFunctionCode.dhall*

```
let FieldList = ./FieldList.dhall
let FunctionCodeType = ./FunctionCodeType.dhall

in
{ Type =
    { dlc : Natural
    , fields : FieldList
    , telemjson : Text
    , fct : Natural
    , timestamp : Optional Text
    }
, default = { timestamp = None Text, fct = FunctionCodeType.Static }
}
```

*DynamicFunctionCode.dhall*

```
let FieldTypeID = ./FieldTypeID.dhall
let OptionList = ./OptionList.dhall
let FunctionCodeType = ./FunctionCodeType.dhall

in
{ Type =
    { idtype : FieldTypeID
    , idindex : Natural
    , options : OptionList
    , fct : Natural
    , timestamp : Optional Text
    }
, default = { timestamp = None Text, fct = FunctionCodeType.Dynamic }
}
```

Ignoring the other types defined, here is how I'm trying to write a let statement using this union:

```
let fc1 =
  FunctionCode.Dynamic FunctionCode.Dynamic::{
     idtype = FieldTypeID.U8
   , idindex =  0
   , options = [...]
   }

in {fc1}
```

When I run `dhall-to-json` on this I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid alternative type

6|  < Static : StaticFC | Dynamic : DynamicFC >

FunctionCode.dhall:6:4
```

I've tried some different combinations on how to use this defined union but no luck. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `StaticFC` and `DynamicFC` are values, not types. But types are needed to define the `FunctionCodeType` union type.

You can easily fix this by accessing the `Type` fields contained within `StaticFC` and `DynamicFC`:

```
let StaticFC = ./StaticFunctionCode.dhall
let DynamicFC = ./DynamicFunctionCode.dhall

in < Static : StaticFC.Type | Dynamic : DynamicFC.Type >
```

Comment: To be totally pedantic, `StaticFC` / `DynamicFC` are (lower-case 't') types, but not `Type`s.  More generally, a record with fields that are `Type`s is a type.  The language tour discusses this in a bit more depth: https://docs.dhall-lang.org/tutorials/Language-Tour.html#types